# How can I track the cursor relatively to my windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I know how to track the cursor with Form1.MousePosition but it gives me cursor position relative to the screen, not actual form.
Is there a way to track it relative to the Form? Even when I move it (its 1000*1000)!
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You probably want to look at [Control.PointToClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient) and its friend [PointToScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen)

Answer (score 1):

You could register on the MouseMove event of the `Form`.

```
this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseMove);


private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Location.X;
    // e.Location.Y;
}
```

Comment: This supposes the Form doesn't contain any Control that can receive mouse input. You could suggest to use a Timer or a class that implements `IMessageFilter` (it could be the Form itself) -- A generic class can be registered (`Application.AddMessageFilter()`) in Program.cs, so mouse activity can be tracked application-wide.